# JOptionPane no button text with custom LNF

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, look-and-feel

I tried styling a custom-made `Dialog` which allows the user to create a new folder. Until I loaded my custom Look and Feel, everything looked just fine:

[image: Dialog without custom Look and Feel]

Now I tried setting the Look and Feel and the texts of the buttons disappeared.

[image: Dialog with custom Look and Feel]

I set up an [SSCCE](https://gist.github.com/mezzodrinker/6aa89cf5ff51e054697a) which demonstrates this behaviour. Please note that the LNF class does nothing except for loading all values from `UIManager.getDefaults()`. If this helps, I'm using Debian 8 (jessie) with Gnome 3.18.1 and the global dark theme toggled on.

Why does this happen and how can I fix the disappearing of those button texts?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not just using the dialog supplied by `JOptionPane` (it won't fix the problem, but I'm just curious why you seem to be jumping through hoops to achieve what you are doing)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Because `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` doesn't allow me to check if the input is valid without having to show another dialog.

Comment: From what I can deduce from the JDK source code, `BasicOptionPaneUI` is getting the "text" for the `OK` button from the `UIManager` using the key `OptionPane.okButtonText` and `Cancel` is using the key `OptionPane.cancelButtonText`, but these are not stored in the `UIDefaults`, I'm not yet sure where they are stored

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hm, I see. But apparently the problem is not with the text, it seems like the buttons are forced to a certain size.

Comment: They have no text, so there default/preferred size is based entirely on the border/margin/insets properties.  The `JOptionPane` uses a custom layout manager for the buttons, but essentially the result would be the same if you just created a button with no text and placed into a panel using a `GridBagLayout`, for example

Comment: @MadProgrammer What I meant was that even by setting those properties the result didn't change.

Comment: `UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Apple");` works just fine for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93930/discussion-between-flashdrive2049-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values retrieved by `UIManager.getDefaults()` do not include the texts for `JOptionPane` buttons whose properties are `OptionPane.cancelButtonText` and `OptionPane.okButtonText` respectively. This causes the buttons to be displayed without any text, causing them to be as small as in the screenshot provided in the question. By setting `OptionPane.cancelButtonText` and `OptionPane.okButtonText` to the desired values, the `JOptionPane` buttons will display the set text. This solution may also apply for the yes/no buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Another common way is to use the [UIDefaults#addResourceBundle(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIDefaults.html#addResourceBundle-java.lang.String-) method:

```
//@see javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLookAndFeel.java
@Override
public UIDefaults getDefaults() {
  UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();
  defaults.putAll(UIManager.getDefaults());
  //defaults.addResourceBundle("com.example.swing.plaf.light.resources.light");
  defaults.addResourceBundle("com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.basic.resources.basic");
  return defaults;
}
```

**Test2.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.SequentialGroup;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new LightLookAndFeel());
            DialogFactory.showCreateFolderDialog(null, new File("."));
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class DialogFactory {
    private DialogFactory() {}

    public static void showCreateFolderDialog(Component component, File parent) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel message = new JLabel("Please enter a folder name.");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Folder name:");
        final JLabel errorMessage = new JLabel();
        JTextField folderName = new JTextField();
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
        layout.setHonorsVisibility(false);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        errorMessage.setVisible(false);

        SequentialGroup hGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
        SequentialGroup input = layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(label).addComponent(folderName);
        hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().addComponent(message).addGroup(input).addComponent(errorMessage));
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);

        SequentialGroup vGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
        vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(message));
        vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(label).addComponent(folderName));
        vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(errorMessage));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);

        final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(panel, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(JOptionPane.getFrameForComponent(component), "Create new folder", true);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(component);
        dialog.setContentPane(optionPane);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        optionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(event -> {
            String property = event.getPropertyName();

            if (dialog.isVisible() && event.getSource() == optionPane && property.equals(JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY)) {
                if (folderName.getText().isEmpty() && (int) event.getNewValue() != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                    errorMessage.setText("<html><body><b style='color: red'>Please enter a valid folder name!</b></body></html>");
                    errorMessage.setVisible(true);
                    dialog.pack();
                } else {
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        int response = ((Integer) optionPane.getValue()).intValue();
        if (response != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) return;
        File newFolder = new File(parent, folderName.getText());
        newFolder.mkdirs();
    }
}

class LightLookAndFeel extends LookAndFeel {
    private final UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();

    public LightLookAndFeel() {
        defaults.putAll(UIManager.getDefaults());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Light";
    }

    @Override
    public String getID() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Light Look and Feel";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNativeLookAndFeel() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public UIDefaults getDefaults() {
        //defaults.addResourceBundle("com.example.swing.plaf.light.resources.light");
        defaults.addResourceBundle("com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.basic.resources.basic");
        return defaults;
    }
}

// package com.example.swing.plaf.light.resources;
// import java.util.*;
//
// public class light extends ListResourceBundle {
//     @Override protected final Object[][] getContents() {
//         return new Object[][] {
//             //...
//             { "OptionPane.cancelButtonMnemonic", "0" },
//             { "OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Cancel" },
//             { "OptionPane.inputDialogTitle", "Input" },
//             { "OptionPane.messageDialogTitle", "Message" },
//             { "OptionPane.noButtonMnemonic", "78" },
//             { "OptionPane.noButtonText", "No" },
//             { "OptionPane.okButtonMnemonic", "0" },
//             { "OptionPane.okButtonText", "OKkkk" },
//             { "OptionPane.titleText", "Select an Option" },
//             { "OptionPane.yesButtonMnemonic", "89" },
//             { "OptionPane.yesButtonText", "Yessss" },
//             //...
//         };
//     }
// }
// public class light_de extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_es extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_fr extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_it extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_ja extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_ko extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_pt_BR extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_sv extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_zh_CN extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_zh_HK extends ListResourceBundle { //...
// public class light_zh_TW extends ListResourceBundle { //...
```

Comment: This looks like a more complex, though good alternative to setting `OptionPane.cancelButtonText` and `OptionPane.okButtonText` via the `UIManager`. +1